# Create a grid to place fiducials

Tags: processing

I'm combining reactivision and processing, and I'd like to have a grid displayed (kind of like a chess game) where fiducials could be placed, and then recognize at which spot they are (A3,B9 etc)
I'm new to all this and I have some troubles doing this

I have this code which creates a grid with processing, but how can I emplement it to work in the TuioDemo

```
// Number of columns and rows in our system
int cols, rows;

void setup() {
  size(640,480);

  // Initialize columns and rows
  cols = width/videoScale;
  rows = height/videoScale;
}

void draw() {

  // Begin loop for columns
  for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
    // Begin loop for rows
    for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {

      // Scaling up to draw a rectangle at (x,y)
      int x = i*videoScale;
      int y = j*videoScale;
      fill(255);
      stroke(0);
      // For every column and row, a rectangle is drawn at an (x,y) location scaled and sized by videoScale.
      rect(x,y,videoScale,videoScale); 
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be a matter checking if the given x,y coordinates are within the bounds of a grid box. Here's a basic example using mouse coordinates, but this could easily be your fiducial coordinates:

```
int cols = 4, rows = 4;
boolean[][] states = new boolean[cols][rows];
int videoScale = 100;

void setup(){
  size(400,400);

}
void draw(){
  // Begin loop for columns
  for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
    // Begin loop for rows
    for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {

      // Scaling up to draw a rectangle at (x,y)
      int x = i*videoScale;
      int y = j*videoScale;

      fill(255);
      stroke(0);
      //check if coordinates are within a box (these are mouse x,y but could be fiducial x,y)
      //simply look for bounds (left,right,top,bottom)
      if( (mouseX >= x &&  mouseX <= x + videoScale) && //check horzontal
          (mouseY >= y &&  mouseY <= y + videoScale)){
        //coordinates are within a box, do something about it
        fill(0);
        stroke(255);
        //you can keep track of the boxes states (contains x,y or not) 
        states[i][j] = true;

        if(mousePressed) println(i+"/"+j);

      }else{

        states[i][j] = false;

      }


      rect(x,y,videoScale,videoScale); 
    }
  }
}
```

You can actually run a demo bellow :)

```js
var cols = 4, rows = 4;
var states;
var videoScale = 100;

function setup(){
  createCanvas(400,400);
  states = new Array(rows);
  for (var  i = 0 ; i < rows; i++) states[i] = new Array(cols);
}
function draw(){
  // Begin loop for columns
  for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
    // Begin loop for rows
    for (var j = 0; j < rows; j++) {

      // Scaling up to draw a rectangle at (x,y)
      var x = i*videoScale;
      var y = j*videoScale;
      
      fill(255);
      stroke(0);
      //check if coordinates are within a box (these are mouse x,y but could be fiducial x,y)
      //simply look for bounds (left,right,top,bottom)
      if( (mouseX >= x &&  mouseX <= x + videoScale) && //check horzontal
          (mouseY >= y &&  mouseY <= y + videoScale)){
        //coordinates are within a box, do something about it
        fill(0);
        stroke(255);
        //you can keep track of the boxes states (contains x,y or not) 
        states[i][j] = true;
        
      }else{
        
        states[i][j] = false;
        
      }
      
      
      rect(x,y,videoScale,videoScale); 
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.4.6/p5.min.js"></script>
```

If you want to keep track of each fiducial within in a grid element, each grid element should have it's own (dynamic) list of fiducials, updated as objects move in and out of cells.

Unfortunately this is not something I can test, but here is a proof of concept based on your existing code. Please note the comments.

```
import TUIO.*;
TuioProcessing tuioClient;

// Grid

int cols = 10, rows = 10;
GridElement[][] gridData = new GridElement[cols][rows];
int videoScale = 50;

// these are some helper variables which are used
// to create scalable graphical feedback
//int x, y, i, j;
float cursor_size = 15;
float object_size = 60;
float table_size = 760;
float scale_factor = 1;
PFont font;

boolean verbose = false; // print console debug messages
boolean callback = true; // updates only after callbacks


void setup(){
  size(500,500);
  noCursor();
  noStroke();
  fill(0);

  // periodic updates
  if (!callback) {
    frameRate(60); //<>//
    loop();
  } else noLoop(); // or callback updates 

  font = createFont("Arial", 18);
  scale_factor = height/table_size;

  // finally we create an instance of the TuioProcessing client
  // since we add "this" class as an argument the TuioProcessing class expects
  // an implementation of the TUIO callback methods in this class (see below)
  tuioClient  = new TuioProcessing(this);

  //initialize gridData
  for(int y = 0; y < rows; y++){
    for(int x = 0; x < cols; x++){
      gridData[x][y] = new GridElement();
      gridData[x][y].xIndex = x;
      gridData[x][y].yIndex = y;
      gridData[x][y].x = x * videoScale;
      gridData[x][y].y = y * videoScale;
      gridData[x][y].w = videoScale;
      gridData[x][y].h = videoScale;
    }
  }
}

void draw()
{   
  textFont(font,18*scale_factor);
  float obj_size = object_size*scale_factor; 
  float cur_size = cursor_size*scale_factor; 

  ArrayList<TuioObject> tuioObjectList = tuioClient.getTuioObjectList();
  for (int i=0;i<tuioObjectList.size();i++) {
     TuioObject tobj = tuioObjectList.get(i);
     stroke(0);
     fill(0,0,0);
     pushMatrix();
     translate(tobj.getScreenX(width),tobj.getScreenY(height));
     rotate(tobj.getAngle());
     rect(40, 84, 16, 50);
     popMatrix();
     fill(255);
     text(""+tobj.getSymbolID(), tobj.getScreenX(width), tobj.getScreenY(height));
   }

   ArrayList<TuioCursor> tuioCursorList = tuioClient.getTuioCursorList();
   for (int i=0;i<tuioCursorList.size();i++) {
      TuioCursor tcur = tuioCursorList.get(i);
      ArrayList<TuioPoint> pointList = tcur.getPath();

      if (pointList.size()>0) {
        stroke(0,0,255);
        TuioPoint start_point = pointList.get(0);
        for (int j=0;j<pointList.size();j++) {
           TuioPoint end_point = pointList.get(j);
           line(start_point.getScreenX(width),start_point.getScreenY(height),end_point.getScreenX(width),end_point.getScreenY(height));
           start_point = end_point;
        }

        stroke(192,192,192);
        fill(192,192,192);
        ellipse( tcur.getScreenX(width), tcur.getScreenY(height),cur_size,cur_size);
        fill(0);
        text(""+ tcur.getCursorID(),  tcur.getScreenX(width)-5,  tcur.getScreenY(height)+5);
      }
   }

  ArrayList<TuioBlob> tuioBlobList = tuioClient.getTuioBlobList();
  for (int i=0;i<tuioBlobList.size();i++) {
     TuioBlob tblb = tuioBlobList.get(i);
     stroke(0);
     fill(0);
     pushMatrix();
     translate(tblb.getScreenX(width),tblb.getScreenY(height));
     rotate(tblb.getAngle());
     ellipse(-1*tblb.getScreenWidth(width)/2,-1*tblb.getScreenHeight(height)/2, tblb.getScreenWidth(width), tblb.getScreenWidth(width));
     popMatrix();
     fill(255);
     text(""+tblb.getBlobID(), tblb.getScreenX(width), tblb.getScreenX(width));
   }

   //draw grid at the end so it is on top of previously drawn objects
   drawGrid();
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------
// these callback methods are called whenever a TUIO event occurs
// there are three callbacks for add/set/del events for each object/cursor/blob type
// the final refresh callback marks the end of each TUIO frame

// called when an object is added to the scene
void addTuioObject(TuioObject tobj) {
  if (verbose) println("add obj "+tobj.getSymbolID()+" ("+tobj.getSessionID()+") "+tobj.getX()+" "+tobj.getY()+" "+tobj.getAngle());
   //update grid on TuioObject events
   updateGrid(tobj); 

}

// called when an object is moved
void updateTuioObject (TuioObject tobj) {
  if (verbose) println("set obj "+tobj.getSymbolID()+" ("+tobj.getSessionID()+") "+tobj.getX()+" "+tobj.getY());
  //update grid on TuioObject events
  updateGrid(tobj);
}

// called when an object is removed from the scene
void removeTuioObject(TuioObject tobj) {
  if (verbose) println("del obj "+tobj.getSymbolID()+" ("+tobj.getSessionID()+")");
  //update grid on TuioObject events
  updateGrid(tobj);
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------
// called when a cursor is added to the scene
void addTuioCursor(TuioCursor tcur) {
  if (verbose) println("add cur "+tcur.getCursorID()+" ("+tcur.getSessionID()+ ") " +tcur.getX()+" "+tcur.getY());
  //redraw();
}

// called when a cursor is moved
void updateTuioCursor (TuioCursor tcur) {
  if (verbose) println("set cur "+tcur.getCursorID()+" ("+tcur.getSessionID()+ ") " +tcur.getX()+" "+tcur.getY()
          +" "+tcur.getMotionSpeed()+" "+tcur.getMotionAccel());
  //redraw();
}

// called when a cursor is removed from the scene
void removeTuioCursor(TuioCursor tcur) {
  if (verbose) println("del cur "+tcur.getCursorID()+" ("+tcur.getSessionID()+")");
  //redraw()
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------
// called when a blob is added to the scene
void addTuioBlob(TuioBlob tblb) {
  if (verbose) println("add blb "+tblb.getBlobID()+" ("+tblb.getSessionID()+") "+tblb.getX()+" "+tblb.getY()+" "+tblb.getAngle()+" "+tblb.getWidth()+" "+tblb.getHeight()+" "+tblb.getArea());
  //redraw();
}

// called when a blob is moved
void updateTuioBlob (TuioBlob tblb) {
  if (verbose) println("set blb "+tblb.getBlobID()+" ("+tblb.getSessionID()+") "+tblb.getX()+" "+tblb.getY()+" "+tblb.getAngle()+" "+tblb.getWidth()+" "+tblb.getHeight()+" "+tblb.getArea()
          +" "+tblb.getMotionSpeed()+" "+tblb.getRotationSpeed()+" "+tblb.getMotionAccel()+" "+tblb.getRotationAccel());
  //redraw()
}

// called when a blob is removed from the scene
void removeTuioBlob(TuioBlob tblb) {
  if (verbose) println("del blb "+tblb.getBlobID()+" ("+tblb.getSessionID()+")");
  //redraw()
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------
// called at the end of each TUIO frame
void refresh(TuioTime frameTime) {
  if (verbose) println("frame #"+frameTime.getFrameID()+" ("+frameTime.getTotalMilliseconds()+")");
  if (callback) redraw();
}
//update all grid elements based on a given TuioObject
void updateGrid(TuioObject tobj){
  for(int y = 0; y < rows; y++){
    for(int x = 0; x < cols; x++){
      gridData[x][y] = new GridElement();
      gridData[x][y].update(tobj);
    }
  }
}
//draw the grid
void drawGrid(){
  for(int y = 0; y < rows; y++){
    for(int x = 0; x < cols; x++){
      gridData[x][y].draw();
    }
  }
}

class GridElement{
  //a dynamic list of tuioObjects - each element will keep track of what objects are within it's bounds 
  ArrayList<TuioObject> tuioObjects = new ArrayList<TuioObject>();
  //coordinates to check bounds and draw
  int x,y,w,h;
  //2D array indices, if needed
  int xIndex, yIndex;

  //check if a gven TuioObject is within the bounds of this element
  void update(TuioObject tobj){
    double fx = tobj.getX();
    double fy = tobj.getY();

    if( (fx >= x && fx <= x + w) && (fy >= y && fy <= y + h) ){
      //if it is, add it to the list
      add(tobj);

    }else{
      //otherwise remove it
      remove(tobj);

    }


  }
  //easy to access functions to add/remove objects from the list, checking for duplicates
  //a HashMap may be more suitable than an ArrayList, as you index objects by keys, not indices (like arrays) and will automatically avoid duplicates
  void add(TuioObject tobj){
    if (!tuioObjects.contains(tobj)){
      tuioObjects.add(tobj);
    }
  }

  void remove(TuioObject tobj){
    if (tuioObjects.contains(tobj)){
      tuioObjects.remove(tobj);
    }
  }

  void draw(){
    pushStyle();//isolate drawing styles from the rest of the sketch
    //draw the border only
    noFill();
    stroke(0);
    rect(x,y,w,h);
    //draw text on top
    fill(127);
    //loop through each tuioObjects present in the current element and draw it one after the other (vertically)
    for(int i = 0; i < tuioObjects.size(); i++){
      TuioObject tobj = tuioObjects.get(i);
      text(tobj.getSymbolID()+" ("+tobj.getSessionID()+") "+tobj.getX()+" "+tobj.getY(),x,y+10+(i*12));
    }
    popStyle();
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help ! 
However, if I try to combine your piece of code to the TUIO demo code (which allows fiducials to be detected and displayed in the window when you run the program), it doesn't display the grid, but the fiducials are still detected
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fb8c10hf1kmwd14/Fiducials%20and%20grid.rtf?dl=0

Here is a link since I can't copy all my code

Comment: Can you post the complete code to your answer so it's easier to test (the rtf formatting isn't helpful)

Comment: Here is the processing file https://www.dropbox.com/sh/0iprzfyo9fcf153/AAAi3ZXm09vEMXN0Xcckxb-ka?dl=0

I combined your piece of code to the TUIO demo that you can find here
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ikaih945j7y0w16/AAA1hPsbdTYvzqoM4BbeOGpYa?dl=0

As you can see, fiducials can be detected but the grid is not there

Comment: The first thing I notice is you're drawing the grid, then clearing the screen (using ```background()```, essentially erasing the grid), so you will never see the grid with your current implementation. How familiar are you with classes btw ?

Comment: You were right, the grid appears now ! thanks ! I'm beginning so not very familiar but would you advise to make a class for the drawing of the grid and another one for the fiducial detection ?

Comment: in this case, classes are just to encapsulate some of the functinality and avoid overly complex arrays of array lists. How do you need to access the grid data ? (e.g. ask each grid box what fiducials it contains (if any) or ask each fiducial what grid box it currently is placed within) ? What is the grid data going to be used for ?

Comment: Yes I need to ask each box if it contains a fiducial or not, and then I have to find out if there is a "path" of fiducials: one fiducial will never move (say it is in the box A1), and the others will be moved around the grid. I need the grid data to find out if the fiducials are making a loop or not, meaning is there a fiducial next to the A1, and another etc until it goes back to A1 kind of like an electric circuit to know if it's closed or not.

Comment: I wanted to modify the code using the mouse coordinates, so it retrieves the fiducials coordinates instead and makes black the box on which the fiducial is (line 130-170):

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/74vu90r6yu4kpkk/AAAnok-4NllSPkSQByN7GRAHa?dl=0

But the box are not black when a fiducial is on it ...